# Getting data on real property sales

Tags: data-request

Does anyone know where I can get data on real property sales and listings, for a certain area? I need data from just one neighborhood, green Valley Ranch in Henderson, NV. I would need the following: `address` (or map position) `square footage` `bedrooms` `bathrooms` `date of sale` `recorded sale price`, as well a measure of how fast the property sold, like days listed or time between listing and sale. 
I see there are some similar questions and I read all of them, but I was unable to find the answer I need. Do I need to scrape this data together by individual queries? Plus, I had the hardest time finding the recorded sales. Shouldn't this be public information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for quite some specific information. I work at Quandl and we have this free database with real estate info: https://www.quandl.com/data/ZILL

If you search for "Henderson, NV" within the database, you'll get data on home and rental prices in Henderson depending on number of bedrooms etc and there's also data on price per square feet. Actually, try this link to see Henderson data specifically: https://www.quandl.com/data/ZILL?keyword=henderson%2C%20nv

And try this link to see data on Green Valley Ranch: https://www.quandl.com/data/ZILL?keyword=valley%20ranch

It might not show quite what you're looking for, but I hope it's close and is a good start.